# @content-desc is not detected - Android testing

Tags: android, testing, xpath, gitlab, appium

Working on automated testing for my React Native Apps.
I have created a test scenario using Appium. 
I can run my test successfully on my local desktop with Android Emulator and Appium app.

I pushed my changes to gitLab and my pipeline FAILS at the below xpath

```
go.filter.dropdown.list.ha = xpath: (//android.view.ViewGroup[@content-desc="filterListOption"])
```

It doesn't detect "**@content-desc**".

Has someone come across this issue??
Any solutions??

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's helpful if you can give some full logs here. if its running in your local then it has to be running on pipeline too. Otherwise maybe there's different setting or config you have in your pipeline.